# Enclose existing IF tests within another

Tags: java, jsp

I have some code in my jsp page that looks like this

```
<div class="navalt"><table style="width:100%;"><tbody><tr>

<c:if test="${param.page > 0}">
<c:url var="back" value="index.jsp">
<c:param name="page" value="${pageVal - 1}"/>
<c:param name="name" value="${param.name}"/>
</c:url>


<td class="leftTd"><a class="menu_link" href="${back}"><b>Back </b></a></td>

</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty more}">
<c:url var="forward" value="index.jsp">
<c:param name="page" value="${pageVal+1}"/>
<c:param name="name" value="${param.name}"/>
</c:url>

<td class="rightTd"><a class="menu_link" href="${forward}"><b>Next</b></a></td>

</c:if>

</tr></tbody></table></div>
```

The problem is that when both conditions are not met, i.e. empty more and param.page is 0 then I end up with redundant html.

I tried enclosing both in another if test but it's not working as espected.

**Revised Code**

```
c:if test="${empty more && empty param.page || param.page == 0)}">

<div class="navalt"><table style="width:100%;"><tbody><tr>

<c:if test="${param.page > 0}">
<c:url var="back" value="index.jsp">
<c:param name="page" value="${pageVal - 1}"/>
<c:param name="name" value="${param.name}"/>
</c:url>


<td class="leftTd"><a class="menu_link" href="${back}"><b>Back </b></a></td>

</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty more}">
<c:url var="forward" value="index.jsp">
<c:param name="page" value="${pageVal+1}"/>
<c:param name="name" value="${param.name}"/>
</c:url>

<td class="rightTd"><a class="menu_link" href="${forward}"><b>Next</b></a></td>

</c:if>

</tr></tbody></table></div>
</c:if>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using c:choose, c:when instead of c:if. With c:choose, you can also specify a 'default', which will be executed of if none of your c:when conditions are matched.